# Break connection to site from the JS console

Tags: javascript, developer-tools

In Chrome I have populate an on line mapping tool (Kumu) with a `JSON` file from the JS Console with:

```
Workflows.setCurrentMapSource("MY_JSON_LINK");
```

where MY_JSON_LINK was:

```
https://XXXXXX/json?key=MTE3.DI4LYA.ZrzRFJ5o7Q5m3nLe6d6JGFISdKI
```

But the Link is no longer active so when I go to the Kumu page I get the error:

```
Unable to open map
```

Is there a way to break the connection from the JS Console? I have searched but have not found anything that works

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm on phone so I can't give you the code, but what you can do is override the XMLHttpRequest methods and then you can manipulate any requests done on the page.

But this must of course be done BEFORE the requests are done so you'll probably need Tampermonkey userscript. Example:

```
const originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (){
     //do what you need
    originalOpen. apply(this, arguments);
}
```

So for example if you want to protect some link from being accessed, you can do this:

```
const originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
const REGEX_TEST_URL = /https?:\/\/XXXXXX\/json?key=(.*?)/
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url){
   console.log("Open: ", url);
   /// if you want to kill access to that URL
   if(REGEX_TEST_URL.test(url))
       throw new Error("Blocked loading of URL "+url)
   //Otherwise allow normal operatio to proceed
   originalOpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

You can test this even here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Tomas, thanks, but I am a complete neonate, I have no idea on what to add to your code to make it work.  Please, if you have the time, could you fill in the details?  Thanks